# Call fetch API in local lambda container running with node 18.x

Tags: node.js, lambda

I have a singleton that implements a get function utilizing the native fetch node API. I am using node v18 on my docker container.

template.yml

```
    Resources:
      Work:
        Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
        Properties:
          CodeUri: .
          Handler: index.handler
          Runtime: nodejs18.x
          Timeout: 60
```

```
    class APIClient {
      constructor() {
        this.token = null;
      }

      setToken(newToken) {
        this.token = newToken;
      }

      getHeaders() {
        if (!this.token) {
          throw new Error('API token has not been set.');
        }

        return {
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.token}`,
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        };
      }

      async get(url) {
        try {
          const response = await fetch(url, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: this.getHeaders()
          });

          if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error(`HTTP error! status: ${response.status}`);
          }

          const data = await response.json();
          
          return data;
        } catch(error) {
          throw new Error(`Error: ${error.message}`)
        }
      }
    }

    const apiClient = new APIClient();
    module.exports = apiClient;
```

Previously, I ran my function on node16.x with node-fetch package dependency, and it worked fine. If I switch to native with node18, it ends on the fetch execution. How do I know this? I tried console.log before and after the fetch call.
This is what I see in the console.

```
Invoking index.handler (nodejs18.x)
Skip pulling image and use local one: public.ecr.aws/sam/emulation-nodejs18.x:rapid-1.67.0-x86_64.

Mounting /Users/codehome/lambda-s3 as /var/task:ro,delegated inside runtime container
START RequestId: 4adb060f-0f02-4f8f-b669-4b55957d2064 Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: 4adb060f-0f02-4f8f-b669-4b55957d2064
REPORT RequestId: 4adb060f-0f02-4f8f-b669-4b55957d2064  Init Duration: 1.06 ms  Duration: 11614.92 ms   Billed Duration: 11615 ms Memory Size: 128 MB     Max Memory Used: 128 MB
```